# Error: Command \texteuro unavailable in encoding OT1. However, \texteuro or € is never used in my text

Tags: bibliographies, font-encodings

I recently begun getting the following error during my thesis writing:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \texteuro unavailable in encoding OT1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

?
```

Also, the error is not immediately displayed as it normally would be. Instead, I had to manually click the log to find the error.

The line points me towards my bibliography reference `\bibliography{mybib}` which has been working perfectly throughout the project. It started occurring once I tossed in a large table containing a rather large amount of references (probably around 100 or so). However, I've tried clipping out the table, clipping out all text in my bib file (both new and old) and I am unable to compile using my build: PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX, BibTeX, PDFLaTeX. I can compile using PDFLaTeX alone. I am also able to compile the whole build if I comment out the `\bibliography{mybib}` line. I use Texmaker as my editor / compiler.

The odd thing is, that I don't have any appearances of `\texteuro` or `€` in any of my files.

With my deadline being in a week, I really hope someone is able to help! Thanks!

EDIT: I was finally able to run my compiling build. I'm unsure as to why I was receiving the error message described above, however.

SOLUTION: The code `\renewcommand\texteuro{FIXME}` allowed for the unproblematic references to get included in the document. From here, I investigated the logs to identify which references were not defined - and fixed these in my bibliography file. This solved my issue.

Thanks a bunch to those of you who took your time to assist!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You probably have `\texteuro` or `€` in your `.bib` file, since the compiler is complaining about `\bibliography{mybib}`.

Comment: Hi Phelype, thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately that is not the case. I've searched through every individual section and no occurrences of either of those are there.

Comment: Could you please reduce your document to a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) so we can try to find out where is that symbol coming from? Or, you could try to load `textcomp` to see if will provide the missing symbol...

Comment: in your preamble add `\renewcommand\texteuro{FIXME}` then the error will go and look in the generated pdf for FIXME

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm unsure how to provide a MWEB, since regardless of how much of the bibliography I would provide, the error would still occur - even if it was empty. When compiling using `textcomp`, the build is shut down saying an error occurred, but when I look into the log, the error is no longer appearing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for answering. I've just tried that and received an error saying that `\texteuro` is undefined.

Comment: move it later then (eg after `\begin{document}` as something in code you have not shown is defining it, or ypu could use `\newcommand` instead but I suspect if you did that the code that is defining it now to make that erro would still do tht.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried that now, and a small development occurred: While the error still pops up and halts the build, most of the references have now gone through. I will investigate to figure out which references might be the issue, and edit it into the problem description!

Comment: You write that you have the same error with an empty bibliography. Does that mean that you can not compile even the most basic document with an empty bibliography? Can you compile a copy of your document, where you have deleted half? What about a quarter? -you should be able to find exactly what line is causing the error!!

Comment: @NiklasBroge If you can reproduce the error without the bibliography, even better. Reduce the code as much as you can. Without seeing your document we can only guess what's going on.

Comment: Hey guys, I managed to run through the build now! I've updated the description with the workaround. Thanks a bunch!

I'm new to this board - do I need to mark a solution or something?

Comment: @NiklasBroge Yes, please chekmark  (accept) and up vote (+1)  the answer that solve your question. If there more than one answer, accept the more helpful for you, but upvote for all valuable answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your preamble (or possibly better just after `\begin{document}` add

```
 \renewcommand\texteuro{FIXME}
```

then the error will go and look in the generated pdf (possibly in the bibliography) for FIXME, and adjust teh text not to have a euro, then remove the debugging definition.